# Linux kernel bootup on emulated RISC-V Rocket Chip: kernel execution waits at trampoline_pg_dir instruction in head.S

Tags: linux-kernel, riscv, rocket-chip

I am trying to boot linux on emulated RISC-V Rocket Chip with single core.

Setup:
Environment: U-Boot + Kernel + rootfs
U-Boot version: 2019.04
Kernel version: 6.3.0
Buildroot version (for rootfs): 2022.02
CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-linux-

So far, I am able to jump to kernel from u-boot. The kernel code is stuck at 'la a0, trampoline_pg_dir' instruction in head.S (arch/riscv/kernel/head.S):

```
#ifdef CONFIG_MMU
    .global relocate_enable_mmu
relocate_enable_mmu:
    /* Relocate return address */
    la a1, kernel_map
    XIP_FIXUP_OFFSET a1
    REG_L a1, KERNEL_MAP_VIRT_ADDR(a1)
    la a2, _start
    sub a1, a1, a2
    add ra, ra, a1

    /* Point stvec to virtual address of intruction after satp write */
    la a2, 1f
    add a2, a2, a1
    csrw CSR_TVEC, a2

    /* Compute satp for kernel page tables, but don't load it yet */
    srl a2, a0, PAGE_SHIFT
    la a1, satp_mode
    REG_L a1, 0(a1)
    or a2, a2, a1

    /*
     * Load trampoline page directory, which will cause us to trap to
     * stvec if VA != PA, or simply fall through if VA == PA.  We need a
     * full fence here because setup_vm() just wrote these PTEs and we need
     * to ensure the new translations are in use.
     */
    la a0, trampoline_pg_dir
    XIP_FIXUP_OFFSET a0
    srl a0, a0, PAGE_SHIFT
    or a0, a0, a1
    sfence.vma
    csrw CSR_SATP, a0
.align 2
1:
    /* Set trap vector to spin forever to help debug */
    la a0, .Lsecondary_park
    csrw CSR_TVEC, a0

    /* Reload the global pointer */
.option push
.option norelax
    la gp, __global_pointer$
.option pop

    /*
     * Switch to kernel page tables.  A full fence is necessary in order to
     * avoid using the trampoline translations, which are only correct for
     * the first superpage.  Fetching the fence is guaranteed to work
     * because that first superpage is translated the same way.
     */
    csrw CSR_SATP, a2
    sfence.vma

    ret
#endif /* CONFIG_MMU */
```

Have anybody come across this issue?
What would be a possible fix for this?

Tried searching for the same issue on internet; did not find anything.